# Same component used in multiple routes is being remounted react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I created a simple react application. It has a header and three other components called welcome, feature 1 and feature 2.

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App';

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import Main from './Main'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Main />
  </div>
)

export default App
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    APICall('/user')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I am header</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Welcome from './Welcome'
import Feature1 from './Feature1'
import Feature2 from './Feature2'

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/feature1" component={Feature1} />
        <Route path="/feature2" component={Feature2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

welcome.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Welcome!</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Feature1.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Feature1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I am Feature1</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Feature2.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Feature2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>I am Feature2</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Welcome, Feature1 and Feature2 are in different routes where as Header is common in all the routes. Say I have a user and I want to show the username on the header. I will make an API call to get the username in componentDidMount() life-cycle hook of header.

Now if I change the route, I don't want the API call to be made again as the username is not going to change. And I thought that is how this was going to behave. As Header component is same in all the routes, I thought Header won't re-mount when I change the route. But that is not what is happening. It is remounting and making the API call again. How can I make sure that the API call is made only once?

Comment: Are you changing the URL in the browser and reloading the page every time?

Comment: @yaswanth yes I am manually entering the url

Comment: If you reload the page, the components are always remounted. That's the way it works. If you use `react-router`, you can see that it doesn't reload the page. It adds and removes components on the page. Try adding `Link`s to your `navbar` (assuming you have one) and navigate using them.

Comment: @yaswanth Yes. I just realised that. Used links and it worked as I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case considering your Header is aware of what User is logged, i.e. App.js state passed down as props, you could use shouldComponentUpdate():

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 // see if user changed
 if(nextProps.user !== nextState.user){
   return true;
 }
// returning false will prevent re-rendering
return false;  
}
```

I hope this is somehow useful.
Have a good day!

Comment: Are you talking about the application state we have when we use redux?

Answer (score 0):

change to this in index.js:-

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Tried that. Still making api call everytime I change the route

Comment: how are you switching the route?
if you will directly hit the URL, it will re-render everything.

Comment: try using <Link to='/feature1'>Roster</Link>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you messed up the routing then, because in your router you have only one route registered, which seems to trigger on any child route change. Also, routes should be wrapped in a *Switch* component.

Check out this structure

```
/** index.js */
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import App from './App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

/** App.jsx */
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import Main from './Main'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
            <Route exact path="/f1" component={Feature1} />
            <Route exact path="/f2" component={Feature2} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
)

export default App
```

Comment: I tried the structure you suggested. But it is still make another API call when I change the route. By the way, I'm not sure if this is important. I am changing the url by manually entering in the browser

Comment: That won't work. React is a SPA framework, meaning that route needs to be changed by the router. If you enter the url manually in the browser, you are forcing a full page refresh, meaning the app and all your components will remount again, and all api calls inside componentDidMount and componentWillMount will trigger.